# Different data sets per subdomain in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am writing a personal bookmarks application and am looking for a way to have totally different content between subdomains.

I have written the application and it works fine, but have yet to implement multiple collections. I have the following models:

- Tag (unused so far)
- Bookmark
- Subject

Bookmarks are categorized in subjects and I'm planning to allow tagging in the future and see if that helps me manage my bookmarks more easily.

The current problem I have is that I'd like to separate bookmarks as a whole. I want to use subdomains like `webdevelopment.bookmarks.local`, `languages.bookmarks.local`, `linux.bookmarks.local` that work with an entire own set of domains and bookmarks.

I am considering adding a new model called `Set` (short for "bookmark sets") and defining sets based on the subdomain.

According to that plan I'd have to rewrite all `$this->...->find`-queries in the entire App to contain the condition `"set_id" = $SubdomainBasedSetid"`.

While it wouldn't be that much work, I was wondering if it could be done smarter, maybe that Cake would only see the relevant bookmark set per subdomain.

Comment: Could you have 3 different databases and just change the DbConfig in one spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your solution is right. But instead of using subdomains, you can use prefix, so you don't have check and set yourself. Since you use subdomains, I assume that these sets are fixed or rarely change. So you don't really need a sets table, just use the set name directly in your bookmark record, so you don't have to convert between name and id.

Answer (score 0):

> According to that plan I'd have to rewrite all `$this->...->find`-queries in the entire App to contain the condition `"set_id" = $SubdomainBasedSetid"`.

As all models extend AppModel, it is possible to edit all queries there before they happen (ie. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). :)

```
// app/app_model.php
class AppModel extends Model {

    public function beforeFind($queryData) { // old query
        // make changes
        return $queryData; // new query
    }
```

However, if you don't want this functionality for all models (or even if you do for now), a better place might be a behavior as this allows you to pick and choose where and when it is loaded:

```
// app/models/behaviors/subdomain.php
class SubdomainBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

    protected $_defaults = array('field' => 'Site.subdomain');

    public function setup(&$model, $config = array()) {
        $this->settings[$model->alias] = array_merge($this->_defaults, $config);
    }

    public function beforeFind(&$model, $queryData) {
        $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $subdomain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, "."));
        $queryData['conditions'][$this->settings['field']] = $subdomain;
        return $queryData;
    }

}

// app/app_model.php
class AppModel extends Model {

    $actsAs = array('Subdomain' => array('field' => 'Set.slug'));

}
```

> - Tag (unused so far)

To save reinventing the wheel, you may want to look at CakeDC's [tags](https://github.com/CakeDC/tags) and [utils](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) plugins (the latter contains [SluggableBehavior](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/models/behaviors/sluggable.php) which will help with generating friendly URL parts, such as the subdomains).